# Why can we drop the absolute value in the solution $|x|=C_2e^{-2t}$ to the equation $\dot{x}+2x=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation

$$\dot{x}+2x=0$$

To solve this equation the steps seem to be

$$\dot{x}=-2x$$

Assume $x(t)\neq 0$. Then

$$\frac{1}{x}dx=-2dt\tag{1}$$

$$\log{|x|}=-2t+C_1$$

$$|x|=C_2e^{-2t}$$

What is the meaning of the absolute value here?

Apparently, the recipe is to "drop the absolute value" and use

$$x(t)=C_2e^{-2t}$$

I think that, technically, at (1) we do

$$\frac{1}{x}\frac{dx}{dt}=-2$$

$$D_t(\log{|x(t)|})=D_t(-2t)$$

$$\int_a^t D_t(\log{|x(t)|})=\int_a^t D_t(-2t)$$

$$\log{|x(t)|}-\log{|x(a)|}=-2(t-a)$$

$$\log{|x(t)|}=-2t+(2a+\log{|x(a)|})$$

Now, $t$ can be any value, but $x(t)$ cannot be zero. $a$ is arbitrary as long as $a<t$ and $x(a)\neq 0$.

Comment: You can't take a logarithm of a negative number so it is an artefact of the method. There are other ways of solving the equation.

Comment: But what is actually happening when we use this method? What is the integration that is being done in (2)?

Comment: You could have simply multiply the original equation with $e^{2t}$ to get $0=e^{2t}\dot{x}+2e^{2t}x=\frac{d}{dt}\left(xe^{2t}\right)$ leading to $x=Ce^{-2t}$

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja Sure, that is another method right, with an integrating factor. But in this specific method of separating variables, what is happening?

Comment: @evianpring if $x$ and $a$ are on the same side of $0$, then $\log|x|-\log|a|=\log(x/a)$ since $x/a$ will be positive so you can drop the absolute function

Comment: What it is telling you (or reflecting) is that $x$ does not change sign

Comment: @MarkBennet This seems somehow intuitively true but I can't quite see it. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Because $t\mapsto e^{-2t}$ >0 for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, thus no change of signed occur.

Comment: With the absolute value you have $x=C_2e^{-x}$ or $x=-C_2e^{-x}$ depending on whether the absolute value changes the sign of $x$ or not.  But you can equally well make $x$ positive or negative by changing the sign of $C_2$. So you need the absolute value in order to use logarithms, but in the end it no longer matters.

Comment: See the first results of [this search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22absolute+value%22+first+order+linear)

Comment: If $x$ is non-zero it doesn't change sign, and if $x=0$ it remains constant

Answer (score 3):

It's clearer to first say that $|x|=e^{C_1} e^{-2t}$ which implies that $x=\pm e^{C_1} e^{-2t}$, and then let $C_2 = \pm e^{C_1}$ to obtain $x = C_2 e^{-2t}$.

Since $C_1$ is an arbitrary real constant, $C_2$ is an arbitrary *nonzero* real constant here. But the missing value $C_2=0$ corresponds to the constant solution $x(t)=0$ that you should take note of when dividing by $x$ at the beginning, and this is why you can let $C_2$ be any real constant in the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to realize the solution:
\begin{align*}
x' + 2x = 0 & \Longleftrightarrow x'\exp(2t) + 2\exp(2t)x = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow [x\exp(2t)]' = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x\exp(2t) = k\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x(t) = k\exp(-2t)
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!